# Webbrowser, detect if there is a PDF reader installed?

Tags: pdf, browser, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to check if the user has installed a PDF reader?
Maybe with a ActiveX component?

Could you please help me?

Comment: Think very carefully about *why* you want to detect this and what you're trying to accomplish. People can read PDF files without an installed plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect installed plugins with `window.navigator.plugins`
This will return an array with details of installed plugins, but this will not work for Internet Explorer. When running this code, IE only returns an array with embed tags in the page. Thanks IE, so useful?

Ok, let's try to work this out. The following function should work in all major browsers expect IE.

```
function hasPlugin(name) {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    var plugins = window.navigator.plugins;
    for (var i=0, len = plugins.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (plugins[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

you can call this function and check the plugin status like this

```
hasPlugin('Flash');
hasPlugin('QuickTime');
```

For IE, we should try this

```
function hasPlugin(name) {
    try {
        new ActiveXObject(name);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

you can call this function and check the plugin status for IE

```
hasPlugin('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
```

You can made this function declaration cross browser like this

```
var hasPlugin;
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')) {
    hasPlugin = function(name) {
        try {
            new ActiveXObject(name);
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
else {
    hasPlugin = function(name) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        var plugins = window.navigator.plugins;
        for (var i=0, len = plugins.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (plugins[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function in a cross browser way. I am sorry, I don't installed any PDF plugin for my browsers, -Firefox, Chrome or IE- so I could tell you exact name the argument we should pass hasPlugin function.

I hope, this will help you. By the way, I did not tried the code in browsers, this is a therocial knowledge on me. But I guess this will help you -hope- :-)

Comment: How this answer can be the correct answer? the function hasPlugin will return true in any case.

Comment: There must be a typo or syntax error that StackOverflow is eating up.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think so - but you could always direct your links through Google's PDF reader by default - which will work for everyone.

http://docs.google.com/viewer

Please be aware that this will channel your PDF files through Google's servers, so you will lose an element of security.

Comment: Please think carefully about data protection. If your user has uploaded a document to your site, are they aware that the document is being processed (and therefore probably also stored) by Google?

Comment: That's a good point @freefaller - I'll add it to the answer to help others to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

This was very useful for me:

[Java script - Adobe plug-in detector](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/detect-adobe-reader-plugin.html)

From comments area, get the corrections for Safari Browser too.